# Event Log Oldest Record Number

Tags: c++, windows, event-log

I'm trying to use the new event log API to get the oldest record number from a windows event log, but cannot get the the API to return the same answer as event viewer displays (looking at the details EventRecordID). Some sample code I'm using is below:

```
EVT_HANDLE log = EvtOpenLog(NULL, _logName, EvtOpenChannelPath);

EVT_VARIANT buf;
DWORD need = 0;
int vlen = sizeof(EVT_VARIANT);

ZeroMemory(&buf, vlen);
EvtGetLogInfo(log, EvtLogOldestRecordNumber, vlen, &buf, &need);

UINT64 old = buf.UInt64Val;

EvtClose(log);
```

What the API appears to be doing is returning the record number of the oldest event in the log, but not the oldest accessible event... What I mean by that is lets say you have 10 records in your log, 1-10 and you clear your log. The next 10 events inserted will be 11-20. If you use the API, it will return 1, not 11 like event viewer displays. If you try to retrieve event 1 using EvtQuery/EvtNext it will fail and not return an event -- as I would expect.

Does anyone have experience with this method? What am I doing wrong? I have used the method successfully with other properties (i.e. EvtLogNumberOfLogRecords), but cannot get this property (EvtLogOldestRecordNumber) to behave as expected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385385(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Update for those interested. I was not able to get the new API to work for the oldest record number and had to revert to using the legacy API to retrieve the oldest record number.

Comment: Mitch, can you link that API?  also, you should "answer" your own question.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363665(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to get the new API to work for the oldest record number and had to revert to using the legacy API to retrieve the oldest record number.

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363665(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363665%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: When Vista came out I reported this, clearly unusual and unexpected behavior, to Microsoft. They confirmed it to be a problem, but stated that they would not change it, since code may already depend on the (incorrect) behavior. It is frustrating to see that this has still not changed in Windows 7.

Comment: The only problem with using the legacy approach, is that it won't work anymore once the the eventrecordid exceeds 0xFFFF FFFF.